# Function convert string parameter to number javascript

Tags: javascript, html

when i call function and give it 154911812952895_154922162951860 it converts the paramter to 1.5491181295289516e+29.
this is my code:

```
<span onclick="javascript:remove_attachment(154911812952895_154922162951860)">&times;</span>
function remove_attachment(id){
    console.log(id);
    console.log(typeof id);
};
```

the output:

```
1.5491181295289516e+29
number
```

i want to return 154911812952895_154922162951860 not 1.5491181295289516e+29

```js
function remove_attachment(id){
    console.log(id);
    console.log(typeof id);
};
```

```html
<span onclick="javascript:remove_attachment(154911812952895_154922162951860)">&times; CLICK ME</span>
```

Comment: [It seams to be working fine on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uam5ykgw/). Maybe you could add more informations on your HTML page, how you declare that first variable,

Comment: I have added a code snippet to your question. Plz edit it to provide [mcve]. Currently your code works as expected.

Comment: sorry i edit in Question

Answer (score 2):

The function argument needs single quotes around the id for it to be considered a string. Without quotes, it will be a number, with double quotes it will error because you are not escaping the onclick event handler which also has double quotes.

```js
function remove_attachment(id){
    console.log(id);
    console.log(typeof id);
};
```

```html
<span onclick="javascript:remove_attachment('154911812952895_154922162951860')">&times; click</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is probably somewhere in your variable or how you pass the value to the function.

this:

```
<span onclick="javascript:remove_attachment("154911812952895_154922162951860")">&times;</span>
```

can't work because you are using " to wrap the command **and** you wrap again the parameter in ". If you run it like this, you get an error.

What works is:

```
 <span onclick="javascript:remove_attachment('154911812952895_154922162951860')">&times;</span>
```

**or**

```
<span onclick="javascript:remove_attachment(154911812952895_154922162951860)">&times;</span>
```

The first option will give you a string output (exactly what you want). The second option gives you the number you don't want.

Answer (score -1):

You're the "victim" of a future feature called [Numeric Separators](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-numeric-separator) (which is at the moment a stage 4 proposal).

> This feature enables developers to make their numeric literals more readable by creating a visual separation between groups of digits. Large numeric literals are difficult for the human eye to parse quickly, especially when there are long digit repetitions.
> ...
> Using underscores (`_`, `U+005F`) as separators helps improve readability for numeric literals, both integers and floating-point (and in JS, it's all floating-point anyway):
>
> ```
> 1_000_000_000           // Ah, so a billion
> 101_475_938.38          // And this is hundreds of millions
>
> let fee = 123_00;       // $123 (12300 cents, apparently)
> let fee = 12_300;       // $12,300 (woah, that fee!)
> let amount = 12345_00;  // 12,345 (1234500 cents, apparently)
> let amount = 123_4500;  // 123.45 (4-fixed financial)
> let amount = 1_234_500; // 1,234,500
> ```

To make your `remove_attachment()` function work you have to wrap the number in (single) quotes to make it an actual string:

```
<span onclick="javascript:remove_attachment('154911812952895_154922162951860')">&times;</span>
```